# Software program (or spreadsheet calculations) to find Borehole Deviation?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, 3d, vba, excel

I was given a bunch of surveyed borehole data (azimuth, depth, dip, geology, etc) and am required to calculate a deviation variable. Besides querying the data and averaging the surveyed borehole results, I was wondering if anyone had any specific calculations or recommended software programs in order to calculate a deviation variable and to visualize it in a 3D view around a planned borehole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a software that could have the capabilities you're looking for, its name is Target from Geosoft: http://www.geosoft.com/products/target. It works with the base software called Oasis Montaj and can be used with ArcGis also. I've worked with it and it's pretty neat, however it's not free and the licenses are quite expensive (only Oasis Montaj is about USD 11k). You can request academic licenses but also you have to pay for them as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Strater](https://www.goldensoftware.com/products/strater) software from Golden Software. It can calculate and display true vertical depth from measured depth (accounting for borehole deviation). You can visualize the data in 3D using Golden Software's Voxler product.